# convert String in time to Time object without Date

Tags: java, date, time

i got problem to convert String time to Time object because it print together with Date.  this is my code.

```
String time = "15:30:18";

DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(time);

System.out.println("Time: " + date);
```

how to convert and print Time only without Date in java.  it will be better if you could give an example.

thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the same `SimpleDateFormat` that you used to parse it:

```
String time = "15:30:18";

DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(time);

System.out.println("Time: " + sdf.format(date));
```

Remember, the `Date` object always represents a combined date/time value. It can't properly represent a date-only or time-only value, so you have to use the correct `DateFormat` to ensure you only "see" the parts that you want.

Answer (score 11):

This works as well

```
String t = "00:00:00" 
Time.valueOf(t);
```

Answer (score 8):

## Joda-Time | java.time

If you want a time-only value without a date and without a time zone, then you must use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new java.time package bundled in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

Both of those frameworks offers a `LocalTime` class.

In Joda-Time 2.4…

```
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime( "15:30:18" );
```

In java.time…

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( "15:30:18" );
```