# convert Date to Time with java

Tags: java, date, time

I want to convert a `variable` of type `Date` into `Time` format . I tried to use `SimpleDateFormat` but without success . 
I used the `SimpleDateFormat` for converting the `String` into `Date`.

```
public static String convDataToString (Date dataconv)
{
    SimpleDateFormat formattoData = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String data = "";
    try{
        dataconv = formattoData.parse(data);
        System.out.println(formattoData.format(dataconv));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return formattoData.format(dataconv);
}
```

But I need to convert `Date` into `Time` format.

Comment: Please provide what have you tried and why it *didn't work*.

Comment: I provided the method that convert a String to Date. But I need to convert Date into Time

Comment: Please provide the relevant code where the problem arises. Otherwise, we cannot help you, only provide some working code that may not fit with your needs.

Comment: the code is posted up

Comment: Ok, try SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss"); f.e., so you get the time only. Date doesn't contain time without date. In contains the timestamp - date+time

Comment: Converting a `Date` into a date that includes the time is a bit meaningless if you don't know what time it *should* be converted to.  By default, `Date` is going to use the current system time.   What time did you actually require it to be? Did you want it set at midnight instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert String in time to Time object without Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451016/convert-string-in-time-to-time-object-without-date)

Comment: @VictorJDotN Please re-write your Question. Explain what you mean by "convert Date into Time format". Explain *exactly* what you are trying to do. Examples of expected data, inputs and outputs, might help.

Comment: @Shrish: when editing, please note that inline code spans (`like this`) [shouldn't be used for highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990), only for code in sentences. Also, please try and improve the post as much as possible when editing to save the reviewers time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `java.util` package we can find `Date` class which encapsulates date and time. If you try `new Date()`, you get both date and time for the current timestamp. But `Calendar` class (`java.util.Calendar`) provides many tools for manipulations of date and time.