# Comparing 24-hour time value from text file

Tags: java, time

I would like to compare time values given in a space delimited text file that reads as such.

*Motorist Tommy Journey Tommy 08:15 08:45 18.3*

I know I can specify objects by creating a scanner to read through the file.

```
try
    {
        File fin = new File("data.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fin);
        ArrayList<String> theData = new ArrayList<String>();

        //read the column headings from the flat text file
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] list = line.split(" "); //this is space delimited
            //objects in the text file
            String driver = list[1];
            String trip = list[3];

        }
    }
```

After ensuring driver and trip string values are the same, I'd like to compare time values but I'm not sure how to go about accessing these as primitive data types. I want to do something like

```
long initTime = list[4];
```

But this value has a colon in it, could I get some help trying to compare time values in a given text file?

Comment: Why does your list[4] have 4 elements?

Comment: you want to convert `08:15 08:45 18.3` to long? or what exactly?

Comment: Use `java.time.LocalTime` and its `parse` method.

Comment: What exactly is `initTime` supposed to be? Seconds? Minutes?

Comment: Oh list[4] was just referring to 08:15 , list[5] would be 08:45, I want to be able to compare the two values, and use the overall time period driven to determine MPH (list[6] being miles driven), assuming drivers won't drive past midnight.

Comment: Duplicate of [convert String in time to Time object without Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5451016/642706)

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. The topics of parsing a delimited string, parsing a time-of-day, and determining elapsed time have all been covered many many times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine number of minutes between the two times?  As in the duration?  You'll probably want to use Java 8's LocalTime.  First parse the date:

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse(list[4]);
LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse(list[5]);
```

Then get the minutes between them:

```
long minutes = time1.until(time2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

That will give you the number of minutes between the first time and the second time.  Assuming the first time is always earlier than the second time, and they represent the same calendar day.

**Edit**: If you want to use primitives only, parse the dates into two integers, split by colon.  Multiply hours by 60 then add minutes to arrive at an initTime that represents the number of minutes since midnight.

Comment: It's all a matter of taste, but I prefer `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(time1, time2)`

Comment: You may use `Duration.between()`. This will offer you options to convert to hours, minutes and/or seconds later.

Comment: Good answer. Just a detail: since array indices are 0-based, you probably meant `list[4]` and `list[5]`.

Comment: Thank you! different indices, but this is what I wanted to do

Comment: @Ole V.V. You're right, I wasn't paying attention to the indices.  Corrected.

Comment: If you want the minute of day as a number (0..1439), I still recommend using `LocalTime` for parsing. Then you may use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(yourTime.toSecondOfDay())`.